# How to one sound in rapid succession in Java efficiently?

Tags: java, audio

So a little bit of background information:
I am making a Top-Down Zombie-Wave-Survival game, and have been using Java's Clip from javax.sound.sampled, I can load and play sounds without difficulty, but in my game there are automatic weapons, which will need to play the same sound over and over again in fairly rapid succession. Currently, each Gun object holds a Clip field, which is stopped, set at frame 0, and played every time the gun fires. This leads to some guns not even being audible considering they fire so quickly. I suppose I could solve this by creating a new Clip each time the sound must be played, but is this the most efficient solution? Is there something else in the Java Sound API that will let me do this easily? Thanks a lot for any help!

EDIT: Ive been told to add this information, looping the sound will not serve as a solution because it would play through the sound completely then play again, but the sounds themselves are longer than the time in between firings, so there will need to be some overlap in each sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a fixed array of Clips, the size is should be derived from experiment. We will also keep an index of the latest sound being played

When the gun is fired, increment the index (wrap around), stop and start the next Clip in the array. (We need to stop the Clip in case the Clip is too long and it is still being played).

Comment: I have seen that, however it would play through the sound completely then play again, but the sounds themselves are longer than the time in between firings, so there will need to be some overlap in each sound.

Comment: Can you add that to your question so that the problem is clearer? As for the solution, maybe you can have an array of Clips (a fixed array, but the number should be derived from experiment), so that when the gun is fired, you will stop and start the next (wrap around) Clip in the array.

Comment: Yep, that worked, could you append that to your answer so I can accept it? And just so you know, 4 Clips in the array works for even the fastest of my guns.

Comment: Edited to only include the answer.